# Get backspace in python from stdin?

Tags: python, special-characters, stdin

How can I check, if I got a Backspace from stdin? What should I compare the input character with?
I can't understand all those explanations about different codes for special characters (is it a character?), so I thought, someone could help me with some really easy explanation.

I want to do smth like this:

```
character = some_function_that_gets_a_character_from_stdin()
if character == 'BACKSPACE': #This is the interesting part
    do_smth()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backspace is at codepoint 0008; delete is at 007F. (Notice how the image that you posted says "7F" in the text. That is the delete character.)

Try this:

```
character = some_function_that_gets_a_character_from_stdin()
if character == '\x08' or character == '\x7f': 
  do_smth()
```

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: Thank you! That works, though it seems, actually, \x7f is backspace, not delete.

Comment: No, \x7f really is delete and \x08 really is backspace. Many computer keyboards are programmed to send a delete when the user presses the key labeled "Backspace". Go figure.